# Strange bug with PHP 'string-as-array-access' feature and phphseclib

Tags: php, string

I use PHP 5.3 on my server, and I found strange bug - 
I need to delete first symbol in string, and I've used

```
<?php
   $str[0] = ''; //empty string
?>
```

Yes, I know about substr() and such, but in docs I saw that

> Characters within strings may be accessed and **modified** by specifying
>   the zero-based offset of the desired character after the string using
>   square array brackets, as in $str[42]. Think of a string as an array
>   of characters for this purpose.

And all is OK, except that in debugger I see that first element of the string wasn't deleted, but it was replaced by space, it isn't a problem.

But in next step I use this string in phpseclib library in $SSH->exec().

And something goes wrong - script works very slow and exec() doesn't return anything (no errors too).

When I've used `substr($str, 1)`, all is OK - fast, correct work.

I can't find answer - what was that? Does PHP brokes string by replacing first symbol to nothing?

Comment: '' (empty string) is not a character. That should not work at all, ever.

Comment: PHP wasn't display any errors. I understand that my code wasn't correct, I just tried to use that feature in this case.

Comment: `unset($str[0]);` doesn't works too.

Comment: @Dmitry You assign just a simple `""` to it. You do an assignment, you don't remove it. And only because you don't see it doesn't mean it doesn't exist anymore as you can tell. You can just trim the string or just substr

Comment: I'm just saying you shouldn't try to put the wrong type of element into the "array of characters" that won't work the way you expect it to and it really should crash in this case. can't fit the square peg in the round hole. just use `$str = substr($str, 1);` if you want to chop one character off the front.

Comment: Yep, I understand that. But real problem that it should crash, but is wasn't. Maybe this topic can help someone.

Answer (score 0):

When you write `$str[0] = '';` you "think" that you are removing the first character, but in fact you are still setting the first character to blank ('') character. As shown here..

http://codepad.org/rYwIqd1u.

Comment: Thanks for the reminder, I am on mobile so missed it somehow.